# How to update self.request.user field in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to update the requested user field when I create the organization from `OrganizationViewSet` as below,

```py
class OrganizationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Organization.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrganizationSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(admin_user=self.request.user)
        data = serializer.data
        org_id = data['id']
        self.request.user.update(organization=org_id) # Error is coming from this line
```

The above code generates the following error,

```
'User' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Here is my User models.py file

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        "organization.Organization", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

So my question is, how can I update the requested user organization? Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` is a method on the `QuerySet` and not on a `Model`

You can do `model.save` as follows to have the desired behavior

```py
self.request.user.organization_id = org_id
self.request.user.save()
```

Comment: Now I got this error, `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'organization'`. I think I already have the user and I need to just assign the organization to that user.

Comment: you are doing `save(organization=...` instead see the code above `save` should be called without any arguments

Comment: Thank you now the problem is solved. But I got another error `Cannot assign "23": "User.organization" must be a "Organization" instance.` Can you please help me how to assign the just created `organization`?

Comment: I solved the problem by writing this, `data = serializer.data
        org_id = data['id']
        org = Organization.objects.get(id=org_id)
        self.request.user.organization = org
        self.request.user.save()`. Please let me know if there is any better option. It is working now which is fine for me.

Comment: you can just do `self.request.user.organization_id = org_id` you dont need to have a copy of the object

Comment: Also updated the original answer to reflect this